# Когда уничтожаются объекты в javascript?

Tags: javascript, память

У меня на кнопку привязана функция, в которой создаётся объект `var req =new xmlhttprequest` и на него вешается обработчик `onreadystatechange` и дальше отправляется запрос. На кнопку нажимаем много раз.

Вопрос, а когда эти объекты уничтожаются? Или всегда будет только один объект? И косвенные ссылки вроде обработчика не считаются?

```
 const  generateRequest3 = () =>
    {     
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
          if (req.readyState == 4) {
              chips=[{lang1:req.responseText}];
              $update();
          }
        };
        reqBody = {"chips" : tmpChips, };
        req.open("POST", "http://....:9091/newchips",true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        req.send(JSON.stringify(reqBody));
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection

Comment: Это я читал. Но все равно непонятно, когда функция отработала, то ссылки уже нет поидее, но обработчик-то висит и работает.

Comment: А в функции вы await не делаете ?

Comment: @Mike добавил пример в вопрос. Просто отправка запроса. Обработка ответа в обработчике. Как это вообще работает? У запроса есть уникальный id? Если два запроса уйдут и придут два ответа, то они оба будут обработаны или один?

Comment: "обработчик-то висит" - да, "и работает" - нет, с чего бы

Comment: @andreymal работает - в смысле он отработает, когда придет ответ.

Comment: Пока ответ не пришёл - значит браузер держит на него ссылку. Когда ответ придёт - вызовет обработчик, удалит ссылку за ненадобностью, а потом когда-нибудь сборщик мусора всё уничтожит

Comment: @andreymal т.е. браузер следит за  readystate и пока запросы полностью не обработаны, они будут плодиться?

Comment: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#garbage-collection

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, то что надо.